# TypeError: fraction_js_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using an external package called "fraction-js" ( https://npm.io/package/fraction.js )

The following error occurs **in my jest test files only**:

`TypeError: Fraction is not a constructor`

for the following function:

```
import Fraction from "fraction.js";

export const multiply = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
    return new Fraction(num1).mul(num2).valueOf();
}
```

In my tsconfig, I've specified:

- esModuleInterop: true
- allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
- module: "esnext"

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you imported the package `Fraction` ?

Comment: You have to configure just to transpile your tests using the same settings. Also, I just looked at that library and it's type declarations are frankly bizarre

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug https://github.com/rawify/Fraction.js/issues/72